# Information/Device For Gaining Superpowers In Marvel Public Library

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, powers, super-hero

I asked [in a previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235418/information-device-for-gaining-superpowers-in-gotham-city-public-library) if there are any comics that show if books exist in the Gotham Public Library that allow you to learn how to gain superpowers.

Now I am curious if there are any Marvel comics that depict someone finding a book or artifact in a public library that allows them to gain powers or abilities. So far, I have not found anything in the old comics I have looked through.

Comment: Thought I had an example in Doyle Dormammu, but it turns out it was the (private) school library that he found the book in.